# Template Literals with Javascript Replace?

Tags: javascript, regex

am I able to use template literals with javascript replace regex?

I have something like this

```
const regex = "~!@#$%^&*()_" ;
const data = "$88.10";
const result = data.replace(`[^${regex}/gi]$`, '');
```

nothing is getting stripped though, so not sure if I just messed the format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> am I able to use template literals with javascript replace regex?

With regex literal (i.e., `/^(.*)&/g`) you can't. Template literals are meant to build strings, regex literals are not strings.

What you can do is use template literal to build the regex's pattern like bellow:

```
const regex = "~!@#$%^&*()_" ;
const data = "$88.10";
const pattern = `[^${regex}/gi]$`;
const result = data.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'g'), '');
```

Alternatively you can create a [Tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) to build the regex for you like:

```
rgx`[${regex}]` // returns new RegExp('..
```

For example:

```js
// tagged template function
function rgx(str0, str1){
  return new RegExp(`${str0.raw[0]}${str1}${str0.raw[1]}`, 'gi')
}

const regex = "~!@#$%^&*()_" ;
const data = "$88.10";
const result = data.replace(rgx`[${regex}]`, '');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I found one interesting video explaining ES6 template literals here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asRu9MPojFE

Answer (score 1):

How about constructing the pattern as string using the template literals first and then create regex pattern from the string?

```js
const regex = "~!@#$%&*()_^" ;
const data = "$88.10";
// suppose you want to remove these characters from the string
const result = data.replace(new RegExp(`[${regex}]`, 'gi'), '');

console.log(result)
```